# Complex SOAP Request - Error: Bad Request

Tags: php, soap

I will try to make a SOAP request. I found many topics, but all time I've get Bad Request.

At first I make this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('h**p://....CategoryService.Soap.svc?singleWsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
$types = $client->__getTypes();
```

The result:
Functions:

```
[8] => GetMainCategoriesResponse GetMainCategories(GetMainCategories $parameters)
```

Types:

```
[22] => struct GetMainCategories {
 GetMainCategoriesParameter getMainCategoriesParameter;
}
[23] => struct GetMainCategoriesParameter {
 MainCategoryFilter MainCategoryFilter;
 boolean OnlyActive;
}
[24] => string MainCategoryFilter
    [25] => struct GetMainCategoriesResponse {
 GetMainCategoriesResult GetMainCategoriesResult;
}
    [26] => struct GetMainCategoriesResult {
 ArrayOfMainCategoryResult MainCategories;
}
```

Now I try this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('h**p://....CategoryService.Soap.svc?singleWsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$request = array('getMainCategoriesParameter' => array(
    'MainCategoryFilter' => 'AllMainCategories',
    'OnlyActive' => 'true'
    ),
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetMainCategories", $request);</code>
```

But after 20 seconds I received this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request in ....php:15 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'h**ps://...', 'h**p://....', 2, 0) #1 ....php(15): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetMainCategories', Array) #2 {main} thrown in ...
```

Comment: maybe try with an "action" attribute in soapHeader :

    `$actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
                               'Action',
                               'http://soapaction.that.was.in.the.wsdl');`

Comment: In the wsdl: <soap12:operation soapAction="http://site.contracts/ICategoryService/GetMainCategories" style="document"/>. But i received the same error

Comment: Has anyone an idea? I have testet it with php2wsdl but its the same error. all time its a bad request